# Windows Load Balancing over many subnets; how many IP addresses are required

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, load-balancing, nlb

I have two hosts that have an interface in 4 different LAN subnets (no WANs apply here).

```
10.1.1.x
10.1.2.x
10.1.3.x
10.1.4.x
```

Assume that each subnet will need a local service of x.x.x.9 as the desired service to be load balanced.  Also assume the two hosts already have the following non load balanced IPs:

```
10.1.1.11
10.1.1.12
```

**Question**

When I set up NLB on the other subnets, am I required to also have a non clustered IP for that host?

Example:

```
Load Balanced
10.1.1.9
10.1.2.9
10.1.3.9
10.1.4.9


Host1
10.1.1.11  <-- Already Exists
10.1.2.11  <-- Is this needed in addition to 10.1.x.9??
10.1.3.11  <-- Is this needed in addition to 10.1.x.9??
10.1.4.11  <-- Is this needed in addition to 10.1.x.9??


Host2
10.1.1.12  <-- Already Exists
10.1.2.12 <-- Is this needed in addition to 10.1.x.9??
10.1.3.12 <-- Is this needed in addition to 10.1.x.9??
10.1.4.12 <-- Is this needed in addition to 10.1.x.9??
```

In other words, must all the IPs on this page be on the same subnet?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each subnet, each server part of the nlb cluster need one ip (it's own) and then one or more virtual ip addresses.

What affect the behaving of NLB is the choice between unicast and multicast:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782694(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782694%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

servers needs one dedicated ip per subnet because you don't manually map the cluster ip to network interface. NLB uses ip interfaces to detect on which network card to publish clusters IP.

Unicast change mac address but need generally to configure switch (which by default don't accept same mac address on more than one port)

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a fixed IP per subnet, just one per machine on the subnet you want to manage them on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes each host requires its own IP and if you want to cluster them the cluster also requires an IP.  A cluster at a minimum requires 2 IPs, then 1 IP for each additional host

Comment: You can get away with not assigning a local IP but glod help you if the node fails.

Comment: Just to be clear, do I need a local IP per subnet when I'm load balancing N+1 subnets (and already have a per-host IP on a specific subnet)?

Comment: In theory you do not have to have the nodes on the same subnet, however I've never tried to do that with NLB as it defeats the purpose of NLB